# How to convert Float to String for Textfied correctly?

Tags: java

I want to convert float number `0.24779509870200961` to string for fill Textfield but the value display in Textfield not correct. How could I do that.

Comment: show us how did you do that

Comment: What about `setValue("0.24779509870200961")`? :) This would do your task :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek I think you mean ``JTextField#setText(String)`` there

Comment: I was joking... I answered in the same style as the question...

Comment: @Vancurry Please edit your post so it contains: 1. What your code is, 2. What your code does, 3. What you expect it to do.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code to convert Float to String for Textfied.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;
public class Test_1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char arr[] = new char[19];
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(0.24779509870200961, MathContext.DECIMAL128);
    bd = bd.setScale(64);
      //  for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < bd.toString().length(); i++) {
        if (i <= 18) {
            if (i == 18) {
                if (bd.toString().charAt(i) > 5) {
                    arr[i] = '1';
                    break;
                }
            }
            arr[i] = bd.toString().charAt(i);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    String text = String.valueOf(arr);
    System.out.print(text);
    // here Add text in your textField
   //textField.setText(text);

 }}
```

Comment: Value of String in this case will be 0.2477951. This is because float data type limits..

Comment: @drgPP now you can check the code. You will get desired output

Comment: @Rafiq Thank you. But when I you code to float f = 0.24779509870200961f and BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(f, MathContext.DECIMAL128); the output 0.24779510498046871. So What different? Thanks

Comment: Now set the output in your textfield. "textField.setText(text); "

Comment: @Rafiq in statement BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(0.24779509870200961, MathContext.DECIMAL128); 0.24779509870200961 is double not float. if you change your code to float f = 0.24779509870200961f and BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(f, MathContext.DECIMAL128) the output result is  0.24779510498046871

Comment: Hello dude, use of double may be better. you can use double.